# What is the opposite command of CleanImage()

Tags: dm-script

CleanImage( BasicImage )
allows to delete an image without getting the dialog: "Do you want to save ..."

Apart from adding zero to the whole image (8k by 8k), is there a counter part?  Like:

DirtyImage( BasicImage )

Thanks!

Comment: See answer below, but can you explain where you would need such functionality? It might hint to a mis-conception or mis-architecture of your script which would call for another solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **No, such a command does not exist, but it also isn't really useful.**
> *Any* action on an imageDocument will automaticaly mark it *dirty* (i.e. needs to be saved), so you can easily do this by f.e. adding/removing a tag; setting a pixelvalue temporarily; moving the window, etc.

The command `CleanImage()` is just a convenience feature really. The actual property *"is different from stored file"* is a property of the the *ImageDocument*, the stuff that gets saved to disc.

As a consequence, the command isn't really doing anything to images which do not have an *ImageDocument*, i.e. image variables which have never been shown, saved, or had `ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()` called on them. You can see this here:

```
image img := RealImage( "test", 4, 100, 100 )
If ( TwoButtonDialog("Show?","Yes","No") )
    img.ShowImage()

If ( TwoButtonDialog("Try closing before cleaning?","Yes","No") )
    img.CloseImage()
else
{
    img.CleanImage()
    img.CloseImage()
}
```

The command really matches to:

`void ImageDocumentClean( ImageDocument imgDoc )`

and the command to check if an imageDocument needs saving is

`Boolean ImageDocumentIsDirty( ImageDocument img_doc )`

So, more typically one would use these commands instead, as I do in the scripts below.

---

The following script shows how you can easily "dirty" an *imageDocument* just by re-setting one of the pixels value. Note that this script works independently of having the image displayed, because we explicitly create the *ImageDocument*.

```
Result( "\n Create Image... ")
image img := RealImage( "test", 4, 100, 100 )
Result( "\n Get it's ImageDocument... ")
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()

Result( "\n Is it dirty? --> " + (doc.ImageDocumentIsDirty()?"Yes, dirty":"No, clean"))
Result( "\n Clean it!" )
doc.ImageDocumentClean()
Result( "\n Is it dirty? --> " + (doc.ImageDocumentIsDirty()?"Yes, dirty":"No, clean"))
Result( "\n Make it dirty by setting the first pixel value to the value it has..." )
img.SetPixel(0,0,img.GetPixel(0,0))
Result( "\n Is it dirty? --> " + (doc.ImageDocumentIsDirty()?"Yes, dirty":"No, clean"))
```

However, I am curious in when such a functionality would ever be needed?

Comment: There is a case when a UI frame allows to hide/show certain images, as a user preference.  While the thread is running, the image might get closed and then the message "do you want to save" is a nuisance.  So I like to clean images during that time.  However, when the thread is done, the remaining images should be dirtied again.  I checked your suggestion and it takes <1ms to execute.  Perfect!

Comment: @EVoelkl That is backward. Leave the dirty-state alone and use the ImageDocumentClose() command with the "do not ask" Boolean parameter instead.